# Reading SQL script

Tags: sql

Hi I am new to SQL scripts and have some problem to read below, especially for the symbols of N'USER11'and 'TV11man^%'. Could anybody interpret the statement including the symbols?  Thanks a lot!

```
if not exists (select * from syslogins where loginname=N'USER11')
    EXEC sp_addlogin 'USER11', 'TV11man^%', 'Lobby11'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `USER11` entry does not exist, add login for `USER11`.

`TV11man^%` appears to be a password.

Normally `%` is a wildcard in SQL.

FYI..  Depending on your permissions, you can open the database:
select Programmability/Stored Procedures/System Stored Procedures
Locate sp_addlogin
Right-Click and choose modify

You will see what parameters are needed and what they mean,

Comment: Why is N'USER11' instead of 'USER11'? What is N here?

Comment: `N` is technically called "N Text" or NVarchar (it is a data type)..  Most of the time, you can put in the text normally..  SQL Server will place the N in for you automatically.